# Is the a way for a loaded Keras Model wrapped into a KerasClassifier without fitting(No Training)

Tags: python, keras

```
def get_model():
    return load_model("model.h5")

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = get_model)
# model.fit(X_train,y_train)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
display = plot_partial_dependence(
       model, TrainX, features, fig=fig
)
```

I dont want to retrain the model as it will change the model that I was trying to evaluate

Comment: well what is the problem here? Do you get any errors, it does not work? Please be very specific

Comment: (My Purpose is to evaluate the existing trained model for the partial_plot_dependence)
I was trying to use the NN for plot partial dependence. However, this will only work if the model is a fitted classifier.
Hence, to run plot partial dependence for Keras, I will need to wrap the KerasClassifier and then perform model.fit(). Since, model.fit() would meant that the model will be trained again and I will not get to evaluate the initially trained model. Therefore, I am not able to achieve the purpose of this project

Comment: I have the same problem as well. I am trying to use a pretrained Keras model in sklearn's `DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator()`. Apparently, it calls `check_estimator()`, which concludes that the model is not fitted because it contains no variables that satisfy a naming convention based on leading and trailing underscores. `check_estimator()` then proceeds to throw `NotFittedError`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, 
**IF** you are trying to import `.h5` files of a pre-trained model and use that for the predict :
then, Yes. you can

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("path to .h5 files")
## if there is a separate weight file
model.load_weights("path to weight .h5 file")
```

after that, you can use `model` variable for predictions.

**but** 
If you are trying to see how the model is trained, then you have to get log files for a particular training instance. And use [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras) to visualize easily.